# Alamofire POST Returning Data

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to make a post request to server. The post request is working fine.

**Issue:** When the post request is made, it returns some data which I need. How can I store/ retrieve that data

The POST Request:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, postURL, parameters: params)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the response closure add 
`.response { request, response, data, error in }`
to the end of your code

ie

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
     .response { request, response, data, error in
         print(request)
         print(response)
         print(data)
         print(error)
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of AlamoFire.
  If you are using the latest version of AlamoFire.
  Try this working fine for me.(Change request arguments based on your need)

```
let url1 = "http://yoururl.com"
let head = [ "Accept": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"] // Adding headers
        let p = ["Email":"anything","Password": "123"] // Adding parameters if any

Alamofire.request(.POST,url1, parameters: p, encoding : .JSON, headers : head)
      .responseJSON { response in
             print(response.request)  // original URL request
             print(response.response) // URL response
             print(response.data)     // server data
             print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

  }
```